# Find count of rows in multiple tables based on a foreign key in a given table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database that contains the following tables I am concerned with.

1. JobAreas (Base table for which I want to query other tables)
2. JobSkills (Every Job Skill belongs to a Job Area via foreign key i.e. parent_id)
3. Jobs (Every job must belong to a Job Area via foreign key i.e. category_id)
4. UserSkills (This table contains the JobSkill that is related to a Job Area)

I am attaching the table structures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to create a SQL query that can give me the number of skills, number of jobs and number of people for various Job Areas. Though calculating Users who offer services in a particular Job Area appears to be tough because it is connected indirectly. I tried to get Number of Skills and Number of Jobs for all Job Areas using the following query.

```
select
  t.id,
  t.title,
  count(s.parent_id) as skillsCount,
  count(m.category_id) as jobCount
from
  job_areas t
  left join skill_types s ON s.parent_id = t.id
  left join job_requests m ON m.category_id = t.id 
group by
  t.id
```

But it is not giving the correct data. Can someone guide me in right direction on how to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are joining along different dimensions.  The quick-and-dirty way to fix this is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
select t.id, t.title,
       count(distinct s.parent_id) as skillsCount,
       count(distinct m.category_id) as jobCount
from job_areas t left join
     skill_types s
     ON s.parent_id = t.id left join
     job_requests m 
     ON m.category_id = t.id 
group by t.id;
```

This works fine if there are just a handful of skills and categories for each  job.  If there are many, you want to pre-aggregate before the `join` or use correlated subqueries.